# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: react-native

Is There Any Props To Disable Keyboard Avoiding View To TextInputs
Example:

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView behaviour="padding">
      <TextInput />
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behaviour="padding">
      <TextInput />
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Now I When I Focus On The First Text Input , I Don't Want Keyboard Avoiding View To Activate Since It Is The First Form Field And Is Visible.
I Only Want KeyboardAvoidingView To Activate When I Press On The Second Form Field Since The Keyboard Blocks It.
I'm New To This Please Help Me Out
Thank You

Comment: This may seem obvious but have you tried having only the second TextInput inside a KeyboardAvoidingView?

Comment: Yes I have Tried that , but for some reason when i click the first input.. keyboard does not pop up in a normal way(when the second input is enclosed in keyboardavoidingview)... i want the keyboard to pop up in a normal way ....and for the second input let KAV be active

Comment: Ok in my experience KeyboardAvoidingView has given me more problems than solutions...what I do is that every time the keyboard opens I use the keyboard height as bottom padding and have my form inside a ScrollView. That way the keyboard never blocks views and I can still scroll my content with the keyboard open. [More on React Native Keyboard](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html)

Comment: can u upload the example code in like github or something and send me the link. please it would be really helpful, if u do that thank you

Comment: I'm actually travelling so a code sample would be difficult but you can have a look at “How to make your React Native app respond gracefully when the keyboard pops up” @spencer_carli https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behaviour="padding" enabled={false}>
      <TextInput />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: Holy shit. 3 years later. this saved me a lot of of trouble. you are the hero!